# while loop that doesn't wait for cin

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

quick question: why wont this while-loop wait for input?
(ing is a string)

```
while(ing != "0")

{
    cout << "Ingredient name: ";
    cin >> ing;
    for(int i = 0; i < ing.length(); i++)
    {
        if(ing[i] == ' ')
        ing[i] = '#';
    }
    fil << ing << ':';
    cout << "Quantity: ";
    cin >> quant;
    fil << quant << ':';
}
```

it just spamms "ingredient name: quantity: ingredient name: quantity: ..." and so on

Comment: i.e. EOF, other errors etc. Generally, you have to check return codes in your program

Comment: my bad, ing is a string.

Comment: Post simplest case in which you can repro this.  Probably just while(ing != "0") { cout << "Ingredient name: " ; cin >> ing; } will be your case.

Comment: stdin isn't redirected is it?  It's possible for stdin to be from a pipe or completely detatched in which case it won't wait.

Comment: Most likely, `quant` is numeric and you have entered a non-number. You **have to** check your stream status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what `fil` is.

I think your problem is that you need to flush the stream with a `cin.ignore()` at the bottom of the loop (or else do a `cin.getline()` to get your input). Otherwise the newline at the end of the input (when you press enter to submit the input) gets saved for the next `cin` which is your `cin >> ing`. So the newline gets used up there and doesn't actually ask the user for new input.

Comment: @Yoan You may even have to put these checks *before* the while if you use cin before this chunk of code.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this code out I'm having no problems (Visual Studio 2008). Please let post more of your code and I'll do my best to help.

```
// CinProblem.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string ing;
    stringstream fil;
    int quant = 0;

    while(ing != "0")
    {
        cout << "Ingredient name: ";
        cin >> ing;
        for(int i = 0; 
            i < (int)ing.length(); 
            i++)
        {
            if(ing[i] == ' ')
            ing[i] = '#';
        }
        fil << ing << ':';
        cout << "Quantity: ";
        cin >> quant;
        fil << quant << ':';
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: bool addRecipe()
{
    string name, temp, ing;
    char tmp;
    int quant;
    fstream fil("Recipes.dmr", ios::in|ios::app);
    cout << "What's the name of the recipe?" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
    {
        if(name[i] == ' ')
        name[i] = '#';
    }
    while(fil >> temp)
    {
        if(temp == name)
        {
            cerr << "A recipe with that name already exist" << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    cout << "----Add ingredients----" << endl;
    cin.clear();
while(ing != "0")
    {
        etc.