# Running cron job which uses stdin

Tags: linux, select, cron, file-descriptor

I have a process which uses `select` to poll the `stdin` file descriptor, when I run it from console it works fine. After I added this process under `cron` I see that the output indicates a problem calling `select` with `stdin` under `cron`. Is there a way to workaround this when using `cron` and make the process think there is an `stdin` file descriptor which receives nothing?

Comment: We would like to see some code so we can guess better.

Comment: I took the code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552029/how-to-make-reading-from-stdcin-timeout-after-a-particular-amount-of-time/18552315#18552315) but I have to admit that this code works well from console and from `cron`. I guess this is an issue with my code, but just to make sure, isn't there a known issue when running processes which require stdin file descriptor under `cron`? (which obviously will not interact with the process)

Comment: I recommend you to check the guide of crontab in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info And try to be more concise on your questions, don't pretend people to open a link, check a full code and then come back with suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did was to check /proc/self/fd/0, in case it's not /dev/pts/something I skip the `select` command. Check your fd 0 using something like this

```c
bool rc = true;
char linkName[256];
const char* fd0 = "/proc/self/fd/0";
const char* devPts = "/dev/pts";
struct stat sb;
lstat(fd0, &sb);
readlink(fd0, linkName, sb.st_size + 1);
linkName[sb.st_size] = '\0';
if (strncmp(linkName, devPts, sizeof(devPts)) != 0)
{
    std::cout << "The application's stdin file descriptor doesn't point to /dev/pts/XXX, input will be ignored" << std::endl;
    rc = false;
}
return rc;
```