# Executing function for some amount of time

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2013

I am sorry if this was asked before, but I didn't find anything related to this. And this is for my understanding. It's not an home work.
I want to execute a function only for some amount of time. How do I do that? For example,

```
main()
{
    ....
    ....
    func();
    .....
    .....
}

function func()
{
    ......
    ......
}
```

Here, my main function calls another function. I want that function to execute only for a minute. In that function, I will be getting some data from the user. So, if user doesn't enter the data, I don't want to be stuck in that function forever. So, Irrespective of whether function is completed by that time or it is not completed, I want to come back to the main function and execute the next operation.

Is there any way to do it ?  I am on windows 7 and I am using VS-2013.

Comment: I'm not aware of a pure standard C++ way to do this but it can be done using operating system features. What platform are you on?

Comment: I am on Windows 7 and I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to supply that information and add the relevant tags. And sorry, I can't help you then.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Windows user either, but take a look at `select` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Not a pure C++ way, but should allow you to determine if a socket (on unix a file descriptor, i.e. the keyboard input) currently has information available to read without blocking.  But on Windows it might only be for network stuff...

Comment: But, isn't it for only socket programming and not for normal operations ?

Comment: How does the `func` function collect the data from the user ?

Comment: Using cin (standard input stream)

Comment: Related to [how-to-make-reading-from-stdcin-timeout-after-a-particular-amount-of-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552029/how-to-make-reading-from-stdcin-timeout-after-a-particular-amount-of-time)

Comment: @Jarod42: From the first answer: *"note that this wouldn't work under Windows"*.

Answer (score 0):

Under windows, the options are limited.

The simplest option would be for `func()` to explicitly and periodically check how long it has been executing (e.g. store its start time, periodically check the amount of time elapses since that start time) and return if it has gone longer than you wish.

It is possible (C++11 or later) to execute the function within another thread, and for  `main()` to signal that thread when the required time period has elapsed.   That is best done cooperatively. For example, `main()` sets a flag, the thread function checks that flag and exits when required to.   Such a flag is usually best protected by a critical section or mutex.

An **extremely unsafe** way under windows is for `main()` to forceably terminate the thread.   That is unsafe, as it can leave the program (and, in worst cases, the operating system itself) in an unreliable state (e.g. if the terminated thread is in the process of allocating memory, if it is executing certain kernel functions, manipulating global state of a shared DLL).

If you want better/safer options, you will need a real-time operating system with strict memory and timing partitioning.    To date, I have yet to encounter any substantiated documentation about any variant of Windows and unix (not even real time variants) with those characteristics.   There are a couple of unix-like systems (e.g. LynxOS) with variants that have such properties.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't expect it to be that complicated.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure.   The thing is, to support what you want requires very specific features of the host (operating) system.   Which windows does not have.   There are features you can use, but you have to specifically design your program (function) to use them appropriately.  And describing how to do that would not work in this format.

Comment: Ok. Appreciate your response. I will wait for a day and if I don't get any more satisfying answer, I will mark your answer as accepted. Thanks again!

Comment: You don't need a real-time OS. On Windows, just use [Asynchronous I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683.aspx), and call it a day. This is safe, single-threaded, and meets all the requirements.

Comment: Async I/O only addresses part of the question asked, IInspectable.

Comment: Which part does it not address? All wait functions take timeout values, allowing you to implement a console read function that takes at most *n* milliseconds of time. If you need more than one console read, just put *m* LEGO© pieces together.

Answer (score 0):

I think a part of your requirement can be met using multithreading and a loop with a stopwatch.

1. Create a new thread.
2. Start a stopwatch.
3. Start a loop with one minute as the condition for the loop.
4. During each iteration check if the user has entered the input and process.
5. when one minute is over, the loop quits.

I 'am not sure about the feasibility about this idea, just shared my idea. I don't know much about c++, but in Node.js your requirement can be achieved using 'events'. May be such things exists in C++ too.