# performing an operation if user doesn't give input in c++

Tags: c++

Is there any way in which I could perform a particular operation if **user doesn't give input** within a certain time interval in c++?

Comment: `fread` and `alarm`?

Comment: Most platforms also allow you to make stdin non-blocking, and offer you a polling framework (`select`, `epoll`, ...) that you can drive with a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Not in strict ISO C++, since `<iostream>` based functionality are synchronous.

Unless using some platform specific API...

May be this [How to make reading from `std::cin` timeout after a particular amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552029/how-to-make-reading-from-stdcin-timeout-after-a-particular-amount-of-time) can help.