# Unblocking a thread from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am looking for a way to be able to input data to the terminal while receiving data from the network , simultaneously.

To do that, I created a new thread `dataCapture` (`std::thread`) that will fetch input using `std::cin`. The main thread is the receiver.

The program needs to exit when the network sends the string "end".

Here is the simplified code :

```
void dataCapture()
    while (! quit) {
        std::string data;
        std::cout << "Enter data: ";
        std::cin >> data;
    }
}

bool quit=false;

int main() {
    // socket creation
    // connection to server
    const std::string quit_value = "end";


    std::thread datacapture_T(dataCapture);

    while (! quit) {
        char recep[1024];
        recv(sd, recep, sizeof(recep),0);
        if (recep == quit_value) {
            quit=true;
        }
    }
    datacapture_T.join();
    return 0;
}
```

That doesn't work because after receiving `"end"`, `main` blocks on `datacapture_T.join()` because `dataCapture` is blocked in the `std::cin` call.

Is it possible to unblock the `dataCapture` thread from main ?

If not is it possible to forcefully kill it ?

*ps:* I've not included locks for simplification.

Help is appreciated !

Comment: Try closing `std::cin`

Comment: You could pass in quit as a reference (have to do explicitly in a thread using std::ref) to the threaded method and then when that's changed in the main thread it'll make the threaded method quit.

Comment: @PaulSanders How can I do that sorry ? Do you mean closing stdin ? If yes, the program actually calls another function that uses `std::cin` after the join, so would I be able reopen it ?

Comment: @RasmusDall I don't think I understand your idea sorry. The problem is that the thread is blocked on `std::cin`, not that it's not able to detect that `quit` changed value

Comment: `cin` is not built to do this. For best results you'll have to use system specific calls that do allow termination or time-out. An example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552029/how-to-make-reading-from-stdcin-timeout-after-a-particular-amount-of-time

Comment: I misunderstodd your problem. Please see the answer by @johannes-overmann below

Answer (score 1):

There is no clean way to kill a thread programmatically, both in theory and in practice.

The standard way to unblock and close a thread programmatically, which is waiting for input (of any kind) is to use `select()` and a `pipe()`:

- Create a pipe().
- Create a file descriptor set for `select()`which contains your input file descriptor and the `read()` and of the `pipe()`.
- Instead of doing a blocking read on `cin`, do a blocking call to `select()`.
- If `select()` tells you there is something to read from the `pipe()`, exit the thread. You can clean up all resources and finalize all processing since you are detecting the termination request within the thread. This is key.
- If `select()` tells you there is something to read from cin, read it and process it.
- From any other thread, e.g. at the end of main():

  - Whenever you want to terminate the thread, write a single byte (the value does not matter) into the `pipe()`.
  - `join()` the thread.

You think this method sounds arbitrary and complicated? It is! Yet it is common practice and you can rely on it to work since it is used by a lot of frameworks and programs.

There are also less favorable alternatives like polling for input (non-blocking) and checking a stop flag. The perhaps most useful alternative is to not use any other thread at all to get the input, and use a single threaded event driven system for all I/O, and just do the internal processing in other threads.

Threads are not a useful mechanism to achieve I/O concurrency. Threads are useful to create CPU processing concurrency.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! I also tried a way in which select is in a `while(!quit)` loop and timeouts each 1 second, this way : if there's input on stdin it processes it, else it does the next iteration after checking on `!quit`. Is that less performant ? Does a call to select with unlimited timeout have a `while (true)` internally ?

Comment: @Jonas: `select()` suspends the thread and allows other threads to run until there is something to do, so this is the most performant way in the sense that it allows other threads processes to run while there is nothing to do. Internally it is not using polling but it is using the internal operating system events directly. But a lot of programs use a timeout of 1 s (or so) as a last resort, in case the pipe() mechanism fails, and actually for simple programs the 1s timeout is better because it is a lot less code to implement it and often the 1s worst case lag for termination is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can close `std::cin` with `ctrl-z`.

Another way to fix this is by going into your `dataCapture()` and checking for `quit_value` in there too by doing a `break`.

EDIT: Consider using atomic as well to keep reading/writing to concurrent threads as well-defined as possible. Don't think it adds too much complexity