C++ user input, during threaded file finding
I have a small console app I'm writing, it does some process in the background with threads, and has another thread that dumps results to console.
Now I want to enable the user to be able to input commands such as exit and it to terminate the program.
I have that working the only issue is during the loop if there isn't any input and the processing has completed the program waits for input so then as long as I type anything the loop continues and the condition is now false and the process exits.
My question is, is there a way to make it so I don't get stuck on the std::cin >> command in my while loop, so it can continue running and check the other conditions that might break the loop?
I've tried having a thread dedicated to input too but that seems to hand when waiting for it to end calling inputThread.join().
I'm using condition variables and setting an atomic<bool> running = false when other conditions are met. But I cannot get the program to exit if no user input is every provided.
Here's a skeleton to try demonstrate my issue.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // create thread pool doing processes, that mark as completed when done
    // and dump thread that periodically works based on a run condtion
    // cv.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(10), []{ return !running.load(); }

    while(running) 
    {
        if(completedThreads.load() == threadPool.size())
        {
            running = false;
            results.clear();
            cv.notify_all();
            break;
        }

        std::cin >> command;
        if(command == "dump")
        {
            std::cout << "Dumping Results: " << std::endl;

            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            //dump results here
        }
        if(command == "exit")
        {
            running = false;
            results.clear();
            cv.notify_all();
            break;
        }
    }

    for(auto& thread : threadPool)
    {
        if(thread.joinable())
        {
            thread.join();
        }
    }

    if(dumpThread.joinable())
    {
        dumpThread.join();
    }

    return 0;
}

edit: If possible I want to keep my solution as portable as possible but If its really difficult/not ideal I'd go windows specific.
I wanted to try make the program as clean as possible so I'm not sure how bad having the OS reap a thread would be.

iostreams are deliberately too stupid to handle a case like this. Often you can hide the read away in another thread and let the thread get reaped by the OS when the program terminates because main exited, but I prefer to fall back on a target-specific (though usually hidden behind a portable library like ncurses) non-blocking IO or event-based input. What OS are you targeting, and how portable do you need the program to be?

@user4581301
I was ideally want the program to be as portable as possible, but I am happy to make it windows specific for the time being.

A Stack Overflow usage note: Reply to comments with edits to the question unless you're asking for clarification on the comment. You want to have all of the important question stuff inside the question where people can find it easily. If you amend or extend the question in the comments, answerers may miss the update.

Noted for future, updated the question. Thank you.

You can fall back on old school DOS, yah that OS your grandparents used, support that still exists in Windows and the conio.h header and poll getch, but I would take a look at ncurses. You get portability and you can put a timeout on the amount of time it waits for user input. On timeout, you check your exit conditions and either exit or go back to waiting on input. Set the timeout to a tenth of a second and no one will care about the lag on exit and you won't be burning CPU cycles polling.

Similar but probably not a dupe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552029/how-to-make-reading-from-stdcin-timeout-after-a-particular-amount-of-time

Yeah, I saw similar threads but a timeout wouldn't help me here, I don't think anyway. Thanks though.

A timeout can get you a close approximation of what you want. you read for user input, and of none comes you at least get to exit the read periodically to see if you need to do something, like exit the program, other than keep reading. If there's nothing else to do, or when you finish any non-terminating other work, you go back to reading until the next timeout.

More advanced is to block on events with a smarter Asynchronous IO tool like POSIX's select or Windows's Overlapped IO. Never tried it with stdin, but this should be at least somewhat portable with ASIO from Boost.

You set up the AIO tool to monitor stdin and another message source. When user data arrives, AIO wakes up and tells you to read stdin. When you want to exit, you send a message to the alternate source and AIO wakes up and and tells you to read the exit message, which you probably don't have to do since receiving the exit message is enough to tell you to exit. If i knew how to do this with Boost properly, I'd be writing an answer right now.

Interesting suggestions thank you, I've been looking into those methods will update once i get a working solution. How bad is it if i set the input to be handled in a separate thread and detached it so the program would exit. Is the thread hanging about after?

WaitForSingleObject(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE),timeout_ms) == WAIT_OBJECT_0 will be true if input is waiting on stdin. Set timeout to zero for immediate result. Set it to -1 (INFINITE) to wait until input is available.

Modify the above to use WaitForMultipleObjects and you can have it monitor for user input AND the exit signal. Probably the most efficient Windows-specific solution.

I've been trying killing /destroying threads with cin, getchar etc.. and always observed cases when the command is wrong.
So if it's OK to have several exe, I suggest using a dedicated process (and maybe another console window) for input, and an Inter Process Communication approach.
Here is a (windows only) example using named pipes.
Not thourough but still gives the idea. IPCs (namespipes, socket etc..) exist on all platforms, and I'm pretty sure you'll find a portable class.
Maybe the system("start ...") will also have to be platform dependent.
main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>
#include <windows.h>
#define BUFSIZE 256
using std::thread;

bool running = true;
unsigned long nb_secs = 0;
std::mutex mtx;
static std::string command;
static std::queue<std::string> commands;

// simulates your calculations
void count_secs(){
    while(nb_secs < 100){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        nb_secs++;
    }
}
// pipe name
LPCTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT((char*) "\\\\.\\pipe\\MethodiclesCmdPipe");
HANDLE hPipe;


void get_cmd(HANDLE cltPipe){
    DWORD bytesRead;
    BOOL ret_code;
    std::vector<char> buffer(BUFSIZE);
    do {
        ret_code = ReadFile(cltPipe, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &bytesRead, NULL);
        if (!ret_code || bytesRead == 0) {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE) {
                std::cout<<"**error** BROKEN_PIPE."<<std::endl;
                break;
            } else {
                std::cout<<"**error** ReadFile failed, GLE="<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
                break;
            }
            // manage errors, more data & cie
        }
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        commands.push(std::string(buffer.data()));
        
    } while (bytesRead > 0  && running);
    FlushFileBuffers(cltPipe);
    DisconnectNamedPipe(cltPipe);
    CloseHandle(cltPipe);
    running = false;// no commands => exit
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // create an IPC - a windows namedpipe here but you may find more portable
    HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
                                lpszPipename, // pipe name
                                PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, // read/write access
                                PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | // message type pipe
                                PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | // message-read mode
                                PIPE_WAIT, // blocking mode
                                PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances
                                BUFSIZE, // output buffer size
                                BUFSIZE, // input buffer size
                                0, // client time-out
                                NULL);
    if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout<<"**error** Creating named pipe. GLE="<< GetLastError()<<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // run input process
    system("start MethodiclesInput.exe");// start /B MethodiclesInput.exe to have all in the same console
    
    std::cout<<"Waiting for client to connect..."<<std::endl;
    if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ? TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED)) {      
        std::cout<<"Client connected!"<<std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout<<"**error** Error connecting to client. GLE="<< GetLastError()<<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    // a simple thread that counts 1 sec loop   
    thread(count_secs).detach();
    // the pipe (commands) reader
    thread(get_cmd, hPipe).detach();
    while(running) 
    {
        // commented : not given in your example
        // if(completedThreads.load() == threadPool.size())
        // ...
    
        // that part comes instead of std::cin>>
        {
            // every once in a while, read the commands (could also check if empty everytime, depending on what's in your loop while(running)
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);// will use commands now
            if(commands.empty())
                std::cout<<'.';// purely informative...
            else while(!commands.empty()){
                command = commands.front();
                commands.pop();
                std::cout<<"Got command "<<command<<std::endl;
                if(command == "dump"){
                    std::cout<<"Dumping Results: " << std::endl;
                    std::cout<<"\n val is " << nb_secs << std::endl;
                }
                else if (command == "exit"){
                    running = false;
                    //results.clear();
                    //cv.notify_all();
                    //break;
                    system("taskkill /IM MethodiclesInput.exe");
                    
                }
            }
        }
        // ...
   }
   return 0;
}

inputconsole.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
LPCTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT((char*) "\\\\.\\pipe\\MethodiclesCmdPipe");

int main(){
    HANDLE hPipe;

    hPipe = CreateFile(
                    lpszPipename, // pipe name
                    GENERIC_WRITE, // write access
                    0, // no sharing
                    NULL, // default security attributes
                    OPEN_EXISTING, // opens existing pipe
                    0, //FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED 
                    NULL); // no template file

    // Exit if an error other than ERROR_PIPE_BUSY occurs
    int l = GetLastError();
    //.. manage errors!
    if(hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            LPDWORD cbWritten;
            //WriteFile(hPipe, LPTSTR((char*)"Hello"),12,  cbWritten, NULL);
            //cout<<"Sent hello : "<<cbWritten<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter command."<<endl;
            std::string command;
            std::cin>>command;
            LPTSTR lpvMessage = (char*) command.c_str();
            size_t cbToWrite = (lstrlen(lpvMessage) + 1) * sizeof (TCHAR);

            // sends message through the named pipe
            int fSuccess = WriteFile(
                                hPipe, // pipe handle
                                lpvMessage, // message
                                cbToWrite, // message length
                                cbWritten, // bytes written
                                NULL); // not overlapped
            if (!fSuccess) {
                int l = GetLastError();
                if (l) {
                    if (l != ERROR_PIPE_BUSY) {
                        cout<<"**error** Couldnt write in pipe. GLE="<<l<<endl;
                        Sleep(50);

                        if (l == 6) {
                            cout<<"Closing handle "<< hPipe<<endl;
                            CloseHandle(hPipe);
                            // try to reconnect or (cleanup &) exit
                            getchar();
                            return 0;
                        }
                    } else if (!WaitNamedPipe(lpszPipename, 5000)) {
                        cout<<"**error** Could not open pipe: 5 second wait timed out. GLE="<<GetLastError()<<endl;
                    }
                    // there might be other reasons  / errors to manage
                }
            }
            if (!fSuccess) {
                break;
            }
        } while (true);

        
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

run
g++ inputconsole.cpp -o MethodiclesInput
g++ main.cpp -o test && test

Hope you like it, have fun!

Quite like this solution as well as all the others suggested. Thanks @Aname

Interestingly I tried the code you provided, and it worked wonderfully but it wanted the /F flag to shutdown the input console.
